# Is there a relationship between the Scala Dotty Compiler and the Dependent Objects project by Nada Amin?

Tags: scala, dependent-type, dotty

We've seen [Martin Odersky announce](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/6HL6lVLI3bQ) [the Dotty Compiler](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty) - a possible future compiler for Scala without all the baggage.

We've also seen Nada Amin release the [Dependent Object Types Calculus](https://github.com/namin/dot) (Dot Calculus) which [has been implemented in Scala](https://github.com/namin/dot/tree/master/src/scala).

My question is: **Is there a relationship between the Scala Dotty Compiler and the Dependent Objects project by Nada Amin?**

Comment: This is a question for one of the Scala mailing lists.

Comment: The question demonstrates a lack of basic research, but I'm not convinced that it needs to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: Yes there is

Both dotty and Nada Amin's project, in their respective documentation, state that they're built on ideas from this paper: http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~amin/dot/fool.pdf